# Selected value from semantic ui react dropdown not appearing when selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I can't get the selected value from the dropdown to render inside the dropdown once it's selected.
The right value is being set (seen via console) but isn't displayed inside the actual dropdown

```
    const onSlotIdChange = (e, data) => {
      console.log(props);
      console.log("slotId fired, value ---> ", data.value);
      props.setFieldValue("slotId", data.value);
    };
```

The actual component is here

```
  <Dropdown
    id="slotId"
    value={slotId}
    onChange={onSlotIdChange}
    options={slotIds.map(id => {
      return {
        key: id.id,
        text: id.id,
        value: id.id
      };
    })}
  />
```

I've had an issue exactly like this and the solution before was to use something like `props.setFieldValue("slotId", e.currentTarget.textContent);` but i've tried this and it isn't working in this case. The `<Dropdown>` component is from Semantic ui react

I have a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/logincomponent-fy12t). Once you get to the splash page go to the `Login` page via the button at the top. Select `Slot Sec officer` from the radio group it will render 3 dropdowns, the 2nd and 3rd dropdowns (`slotId` and `deviceId`) are where I'm having the issue. If you pull up the console and make a selection the value is getting set correctly but the value doesn't appear in the dropdown once it's selected.

The code for the dropdowns are in `getSlotIds` and `getDeviceIds` classes. and the `onChange` methods are inside `FormikLoginForm` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not setting the state after the user select the value, like you did in "Slot Security Officer Role" (this is correct, see line 246 in your codesandbox).
For example, to fix "device id" dropdown, after line 258, I put this code in line 259:

> this.setState({deviceId: data.value});

and it works. The same need to be done for slotId, after line 253:

> this.setState({slotId: data.value});

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.